# Interpertation $X_{\tau}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let's say $X_i$ iid with $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)$ and $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^nX_i$.
We also define the stopping time $\tau= \inf\{k:X_k=1 \}$.

How do you interpret the random variable $X_\tau$?

Comment: $X_{\tau} = 1$ as a random variable : $\tau$ is the first time that $X_k = 1$, so $X_{\tau} =1$ always. Or is there some mistake in what you wrote?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes that is also what I thought but then $X_\tau$ is just a constant?

Comment: Yes, $X_{\tau}$ is the boring old constant $1$, unfortunately. There may be better things to track in your setup.